# copying excel picture to to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an excel macro that will copy a sheet from 1 workbook and create a new workbook and remove all the calculations in it.

The problem I am having is copying the logo over.  When I run my macro it will hang from time to time either on the picture copy or the picture paste.
This is what I have.  I have tried(as you can see from the commented out lines) several fixes.

```
    Sub CopySheets(Actbook As String, newfilestr As String, filestr As String,Sheetstr As String)
    '
    ' NewPriceSheets Macro
    '

    '

        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newfilestr, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        Windows(Actbook).Activate
        Worksheets(Sheetstr).Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows(filestr).Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Windows(Actbook).Activate
        Worksheets(Sheetstr).Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
        'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Copy

        'Selection.Copy
        Windows(filestr).Activate
        'Range("A1").Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets(1).Paste Range("A1")

        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Windows(Actbook).Activate
```

Comment: You will make it a lot easier for people to help you if they can just copy/paste your code into the VBE and not have to edit it to get rid of syntax errors caused by `>` signs in weird spots.  To help us, just copy/paste your entire code from your VBE into the question, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to indent it 4 characters.

Comment: So it works sometimes?

Comment: save the picture to a shared drive location and import it from there. either do this through the code itself (if it's dynamic) or store the picture in the drive and insert into new book each time its needed. this seems a bit cludgy, but I ran into this issue in the past and that solved it w/o failing at all.

Comment: SuperStew, yes it does work sometimes.  I get the error message copy or past failed, and then I click the continue button and it will then do 2 or 3 more more.  Sometimes it does them all with no problem.

Comment: YowE3K,  I did copy the code into the question.  I put the whole Procedure in it so people would be able to see what was going on before I did the picture copy.  I thought I followed the formatting commands correctly.

Sorry about the > that was because I used the wrong formatting before thought I had gotten them all

Comment: YowE3k, I think I cleaned it up and got rid of the extra characters now.

Comment: Scott,  I'll see about trying that.  I was trying to get the spreadsheet and the code as a single location template.   But, copy it to an external file and then pasting it and then deleting the file might just work.

Comment: You could try referencing the source/target workbooks directly (instead of the often untrustworthy .activate)
`Workbooks(Actbook).Sheets(Sheetstr).Shapes("Picture 1").Copy` & `Workbooks(filestr).Sheets(1).Paste Workbooks(filestr).Sheets(1).Range("A1")` This way VBA has less chance of getting confused.

Comment: Slaqr-Tried your suggestion and it still got confused about half way through the list of sheets the macro creates.  Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: So far the best way I have found to handle the logo issue.

I removed it from the above subroutine and created a new subroutine, that copies the logo 1 time, and then opens each spreadsheet and pastes into the sheet. then saves and closes the spreadsheet.